# Android Studio Tutorial (Error with referencing xml file)

Tags: android-studio

Error when transitioning from first activity to next activity.

Cant seem to reference the R.layout.activity_display_message even though its under that folder,
when I type out the R.layout portion, it only autofills with activity_main.xml and cant reference the activity_display_message.xml file.

```
package com.example.friendmeter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```